# Eager loading of Seam components that are not application or session scoped

Tags: seam

This is my first question so let me know if I'm doing something I shouldn't. I have searched the Seam documentation and the forums about eagerly loading components in Seam, which normally loads components lazily. I only came across one annotation:

```
@Startup
```

This annotation only works for the APPLICATION and SESSION scopes as detailed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.3.CR1/reference/en-US/html/annotations.html) (section 27.1).

Is there a way to eagerly load components in other scopes? I am specifically hoping to eagerly load a component in the EVENT scope.

We are currently developing for JBoss 5.1.0.GA and so are using Seam 2.1.0.GA.

Thanks,

Gary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put in your component an @Observer method using an event that you know will be raised at the beginning of the request, maybe `org.jboss.seam.beforePhase`.

I cannot imagine a reason for having a component instantiated in such a way, though. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the observer pattern within Seam but I'm sure I can figure it out. I agree with you that it is a very strange requirement. We are using a legacy DAO framework (SqlB) that uses a thread local to initialize the database connection. Since it is always possible for a JSF request to be handled by a new thread, I wanted to somehow cause this initialization at the start of every request so I'm always covered. Is there a better way to acheive this?

Comment: You could wrap your DAO in an Event scoped Seam component. In this component you can have an init() method annotated with @Create where the database connection is initialized. You may find useful having another method annotated with @Destroy in order to close that connection at the end of the request.

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty close to what I have although I was using the constructor. @Create sounds better, I don't like to have more than initializers in my constructors.